# Alpine Linux and package versioning: can the license change in a release patch?

Tags: licensing

Looking at https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages, almost every single package in Alpine Linux is versioned as `a.b.c-rd` where `a` `b` `c` `d` are numbers, `d` is the "patch release" of the version `a.b.c`.

As the name implies, I suppose the patch release is a bug or security fix.

**What about the licensing of the package? Is it possible that the license of a package is changing within a patch release, or can we ensure that the license is always the same within for a fixed `a.b.c` version, whatever `d` is?**

Background is legal compliance: when we deliver a software based on Alpine Linux (delivered as Docker container), we need to ensure that the license of every single component is properly defined and delivered with our software. 
But "clearing" a component requires getting the source code, and is always time consuming. I see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496755/how-to-get-the-source-code-used-to-build-the-packages-of-the-base-alpine-linux-d/) how to get the exact source code of a package, but this is much more complex that getting just the tag of the related GitHub repository.

So for compliance purposes, if the license remains the same, I would like to take any package of version `a.b.c` and ignore the release patch. What do you think?

Answer (score 6):

Version numbers are, at best, a social contract between developers, packagers, and end users. You should not assume that version numbers will satisfy SemVer with respect to legal aspects like licensing. [Alpine Linux does document policies on package names, version numbers, and licensing](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Package_policies), but these are too flexible to be useful for you.

You should not assume that version numbers have any general meaning at all, other than maybe that they are a monotonically increasing sequence. I notice that there are Alpine packages including software I wrote, and the Alpine packagers did not reach out to me to check what I mean by the version numbers I chose.

However, if you are concerned about unexpected license changes, you may be able to write scripts that detect such changes. For example, you could extract the `license` field from the APKBUILD file, though this is just package metadata and not the actual license. Packagers too are only human, and might fail to notice when this metadata has to be updated.

If you want an easier time with Open Source license compliance, I would humbly suggest choosing a Linux distro with more thorough processes. Don't get me wrong, the Alpine project is *great*, but the Debian community cares a lot about proper licensing, and has built-in mechanisms for distributing licenses and source code for packages. Ultimately, this is a business decision for you how much you care about container image size, license compliance, and the effort necessary to achieve those.

Comment: Not exactly a version _number_ but I do have packages on my systems with versions like 2020Jun07, 1.9beta6, or 0.071220.c. These will not monotonically increase. They are not packages included in any distribution but are scientific packages. From a real distribution (OEL8) I see versions 4.999.9-23.beta.20220509git, 1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5, and 1.8.B59BrZX-8. Yes, version strings cannot be assumed to have real meaning.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was expecting something like that... I remember another thread about SemVer vs License: the license is 'orthogonal' (and Independent) to the version so that the version does not tell anything about the license.
Still, I wish the open source community is increasing a version fix for any license change: having so in the SemVer 'best practices' will help many businesses.

Comment: Anyway, after discussing internally, we will go with my suggested approach, taking the 'risk' of such a version change, but hoping the Alpine-Linux community did not change any license in a patch release.

Comment: as for Alpine vs Debian, we chose Debian-slim in another team whose docker images are delivered on a computer, but went with Alpine here because our docker images are delivered on a IoT device where size still matters: Alpine base image are simply smaller. If the size difference fade when we start adding many packages, we try to keep them as small as possible.

Comment: @EricBDev Sounds like a plan. Most people and organizations that publish Open Source software are not out there to get you, so a good faith effort to comply with the licenses is typically OK. If a license change slipped through the cracks, it will often be sufficient to respond along the lines “oops, thanks for telling me, I'll fix that right away”. However, there's always some remaining risk, and it's a business decision how much risk you'll tolerate. Also, license changes are pretty rare to start with. I'm also glad that Alpine stopped packaging MongoDB after their license change.

Comment: In between, I also received an answer from the alpine community where I asked the same question in their user mailing list.
Konstantin K. 's answer confirms yours, amon:
"revbumps can alter package build options. New options can pull new dependencies. New deps can bring new licenses.  As for fetching sources - if you find working with APKBUILDS too hard, pkgs.a.o has links to build logs for every package, maybe parsing such logs will be easier?"
So yes, working with APKBUILDS or their logs will be the proper way, but we'll start with the shortcut proposal.

Comment: @EricBDev what kind of IoT devices? Being in the industry myself, I know that a lot of devices are moving towards eMMC, and the *smallest* eMMC you can buy nowadays is 8 GB - so the 73 MB of difference on Alpine vs Debian shouldn't matter. Especially since Docker has *excellent* decoupling, and, to my understanding, you pay the cost only once per layer - if you have ten images, all based on `debian:bullseye-slim`, you only pay the 70 MB once.

Comment: 73 MB do not matter on 1 container, but if you have 10 or 50, this is another story. The business teams had the great idea to save on hardware and provide some lower cost devices with only those 8 GB eMMC but with ~4 GB available (OS + backup hidden partition). We offer a marketplace of applications, 1 app = 1 or more docker services. Think smartphone with Apple store of Google Play.
(btw, I hate all these Android apps taking 300 MB or more only for the basic features, too many companies just don't care about fat output, especially when you start using electron and co...)

Comment: @EricBDev The technical point here is that on each device, container layers are deduplicated. These 70MB are a once-per-device overhead, not a per-image overhead, as long as all images use the same base image. If you want smaller images, also consider looking at other container runtimes. For example, Flatpak also uses the OCI image format, but delivers and stores them with per-file deduplication, making base images less relevant. (However Flatpak is not Docker-compatible since it uses different metadata).

Comment: thanks for this addition, this is a very good point I will need to clarify with my colleagues: eventually, choosing whatever base image not matter so much on the long run, but keeping the same base image for all container will obviously save more!
(like the stupid commercials: buy more to save more...)

Comment: *docker system df -v*  is the key cmd to see the shared vs unique size: better have a bigger shared base than a tiny one! debian-slim vs alpine is indeed fading quickly!